# android+php not able to upload image?

Tags: php, android, phpmyadmin

I am using localhost for php.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

public class ImageUpload {
    HttpURLConnection _httpurlconnection;
    DataOutputStream _dos;
    DataInputStream _dis;
    String _serverurl="http://192.168.1.11/project/imageupload.php";
    String _lineend= "\r\n";
    String _twohyphens= "--";
    String _boundry="*****";
    int _bytesread, _bytesavailable, _buffersize;
    byte[] _buffer;
    int _maxbuffersize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    public void uploadImage(String _filepath) {
        try {
            FileInputStream _fis = new FileInputStream(new File(_filepath));
            URL _url = new URL(_serverurl);
            _httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
            _httpurlconnection.setDoInput(true);
            _httpurlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
            _httpurlconnection.setUseCaches(false);
            _httpurlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            _httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            _httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Connection-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundry=" + _boundry);
            _dos = new DataOutputStream(_httpurlconnection.getOutputStream());
            _dos.writeBytes(_twohyphens + _boundry + _lineend);
            _dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                + _filepath + "\"" + _lineend);

            _dos.writeBytes(_lineend);

            _bytesavailable = _fis.available();
            _buffersize = Math.min(_bytesavailable, _maxbuffersize);
            _buffer = new byte[_buffersize];
            _bytesread = _fis.read(_buffer, 0, _buffersize);


            while (_bytesread > 0) {


                _dos.write(_buffer, 0, _buffersize);
                _bytesavailable = _fis.available();
                _buffersize = Math.min(_bytesavailable, _maxbuffersize);
                _bytesread = _fis.read(_buffer, 0, _buffersize);

            }
            _dos.writeBytes(_lineend);
            _dos.writeBytes(_twohyphens + _boundry + _twohyphens + _lineend);

            int responsecode = _httpurlconnection.getResponseCode();
            String responsemessage = _httpurlconnection.getResponseMessage();
            _fis.close();
            _dos.flush();
            _dos.close();

            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_httpurlconnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                Log.i("----------------",">>"+line);
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my php  code.

```
<?php

$target_path  = "/var/www/project";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

But i am getting Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile at line 5.
can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `_filepath` folder you're giving the server does not exist on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The undefined index warning shows that for whatever reason, the file `uploadedfile` is not present in the request.

There are a few common caveats with this problem that initially relate to configuration directives in the php.ini file.

1. Are your upload size ceilings set high enough?  These are in the `max_post_size` and `upload_max_filesize` directives.
2. Is the timeout for the upload long enough for large files? `max_execution_time`
3. Is the path for uploaded temporary files configured correctly and writable?

Narrowing those down, the fault usually lies in the client code, be it just html/js and a forgotten `enctype` in the form in a web browser, or native code on a mobile device like you have.

I would recommend looking into an android library to help you build the request object, as this can be tricky with a `multipart` type request.  There are ways to do this with the `org.apache` libs that don't necessitate writing the actual text of the request like you are attempting.

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

Comment: +1 "for suggesting android library". But can you tell me what is the problem with this android code.